# Enable Lubuntu 19.04 auto-login after installation

Tags: lubuntu, login, 19.04, auto-login, sddm

There is a [guide here](https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html?highlight=autologin) to disable auto-login after installation Lubuntu 19.04, but I couldn't find a way to enable it.

The only information about how to enable/disable it is as follows, but there is no details how to re-enable it.

> If you have autologin enabled and want to disable autologin open the
>   file /etc/sddm.conf as root. To do this run
>
> lxqt-sudo featherpad
>
> and open /etc/sddm.conf. Then to disable autologin remove the entire
>   line [autologin].

Existing **/etc/sddm.conf** config

```
user@linux:~$ cat -n /etc/sddm.conf
     1  [Autologin]
     2  Session=Lubuntu
     3  
user@linux:~$
```

Comment: If your username is *sabrina*, insert *User=sabrina* immediately below *[Autologin]* (and above *Session=Lubuntu*). Doing so will enable Autologin. If you want to disable Autologin, comment out the line you added.

Comment: And why do you want *Autologin*, any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

In Lubuntu 19.04:
Add a line under the `[Autologin]` section with `User=<your user account name>`

```
x:y~# more /etc/sddm.conf
```

[Autologin]

```
User=<your user account name>
```

Session=Lubuntu